# How to display the selected option in multiple select box that are viewable by default

Tags: html, css

How can I display the selected option in a multi select box that can already be view.

There many options in a multi select box, so it create an scrollbar. My problem is when in ie the selected option cannot be see until you scroll it down. While in FF and chrome is not a problem.

Is this ie browser behavior or I can fix it using some style?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its almost a month and I don't get any specific answer for this. I guess this is an IE browser behavior. I haven't checked it with IE9 but IE6 to 8 display the same results. So I can say this is the IE way to display the default selected option in multiple select form.

Answer (score 0):

Implement this : http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried it, but didn't have the result the I want. I guess this is behavior of IE that it always show the top most option which can be occupy by the height of select box. Note: I used only EI7 and IE8 and for the other IE version I don't if the same result.